# How to access private method from Spring service?

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have a service with public methods for database manipulation marked with `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation.

I want to access private method (without Transactional annotation) via Java reflection: `service.getClass().getDeclaredMethod('privateMethod', args)`.

When I call it, I fetch `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`. When I delete all the `@Transactional` annotated methods, it works. Is there any reason for such behaviour and how can I solve it?

```
public class MyService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Integer publicMethodMarkedWithTransactional(int a, int b) {
        //couple of database requests
        return privateMethod(b, a);
    }

    private Integer privateMethod(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}

public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void test() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Method privateMethod = service.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("privateMethod", int.class, int.class);
        privateMethod.setAccessible(true);
        int res = (int) privateMethod.invoke(service, 5, 10);
        assertEquals(5 + 10, res);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you really need spring inside your test? You could just mock all the necessary calls with `Mockito`. This would then allow you to call `publicMethodMarkedWithTransactional()` directly

Comment: Yes, there is a reason: Transaction handling is based on proxies. You're trying to call a private method on a transactional proxy. The proxy only implements the public methods of the service, because you're not supposed to use reflection and call private methods. They're private for a reason. If you need to call a method of your service from outside of this service, make it public.

Comment: You should ideally annotate `MyService` with `@InjectMocks` of Mockito, then call `service. publicMethodMarkedWithTransactional` passing the parameters. This would enable you to internally test `privateMethod` too.

Comment: @Michael yes, that's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import [`ReflectionUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/util/ReflectionUtils.html):

```
import org.springframework.data.util.ReflectionUtils;
```

And the test will look something like this:

```
@Test
public void test() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
   Method privateMethod = ReflectionUtils.findRequiredMethod(MyService.class, "privateMethod", int.class, int.class);
    int res = (int) privateMethod.invoke(service, 5, 10);
    assertEquals(5 + 10, res);
}
```

However, I would recommend to not write tests in this way - you should find a way to test your API. Private methods are not part of the API, and testing this way makes your tests much more fragile.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a reason: transaction handling is based on proxies. You're trying to call a private method on a transactional proxy.

The proxy only implements the public methods of the service, because you're not supposed to use reflection and call private methods. They're private for a reason.

If you need to call a method of your service from outside of this service, make it public.

Comment: thanx for the explanation, I needed this method only for test purposes

Comment: @AlexanderMakeev A test which relies on implementation details is almost always a bad test